# Moving all elements up one and down level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying a few items in a list that I want to be able to move up and down one level in it's tree when I click a certain button.

```
<button class="prev">Previous</div>

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<button class="next">Next</div>
```

When I click on the "next" button, I want all the elements to move down one level, so `item 1` would take `item 2` place and so on. When I click the "previous" button, the opposite must happen - `item 1` would take the place of `item 6` and `item 6` would take the place of `item 5` and so back and so forth.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const images = $("ul > li");

    $(".prev").on("click", () => {
        for(const img of images) {
            $(img).insertBefore($(img).prev());
        }
    });
});
```

But this is causing problems because it skips every second element sometimes and is not moving them accordingly.

How can I achieve the outcome I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only ever need to move one item.

When `.next` is clicked, take the last item and move it to the first position using `.prependTo()`.

When `.prev` is clicked, take the first item and move it to the last position using `.appendTo()`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".prev").on("click", () => {
        $("ul > li").first().appendTo("ul");
    });
  
    $(".next").on("click", () => {
        $("ul > li").last().prependTo("ul");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="prev">Previous</button>

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: The explanation really made it click for me. I didn't think about the fact I only had to move one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

if you modify your html a bit, then you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".move").on("click", () => {
    for (const img of $("ul > li")) {
      if($(this).data("target")=="next")
        $(img).insertAfter($(img).prev());
      else
        $(img).insertBefore($(img).prev());
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".move").on("click", () => {
    for (const img of $("ul > li")) {
      if($(this).data("target")=="next")
        $(img).insertAfter($(img).prev());
      else
        $(img).insertBefore($(img).prev());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="move" data-target="prev">Previous</button>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<button class="move" data-target="next">Next</div>
```